# ContextMenu Login Screen Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to build in .xaml a Context Menu which i can no longer find in my library's so i switched to trying PopUp.

Which seems to be working i just cant view it, i need it to run first thing when my Application Loads because it will work as a log in Screen.

Can any one help me figure out how to Make this visible Right after initialization of the application?

Thank you in advance!

Keeano Martin.

some Code.
(.xaml)

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <Popup x:Name="loginPopUpwindow" Height="250" Width="300" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,160,0,0" Name="loginTextBlock" Text="Login" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474"/>
        </Popup>
        <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,160,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" />
    </Grid>
```

(C#)

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loginPopUpwindow.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to open it in the Loaded Page event?

Comment: @Waleed- I will try that real quick.

Comment: As a side-note, were you looking for the Context Menu from the WP7 Silverlight Toolkit? It is explained [here](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/02/WP7-Tip-of-the-Day-Silverlight-Toolkit-Context-Menus.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML, did you try

```
<Popup IsOpen="True"></Popup>
```

to make it show as soon as the XAML loads?
It works in a desktop program.

Comment: i tried this, it fits in the code but will not produce the PopUp.

Comment: An alternative would be to use a separate page as the login page, and then go to the MainPage when it's successful. If you want it to remember login, just have the login page check against the stored results on load and go to the MainPage instantly.

Comment: this is how i originally had it set up and it was working perfect.Now i have to write it so that the page falls off the stack and i realized that if its a popup it will never be saved to the stack meaning they can not re-authenticate themselves.